# Symfony2: how to refer to images in root resources in css

Tags: css, image, url, symfony, assetic

Apart from having css, js and images in bundles, I also have some in the App/Resources/public folder of my Symfony2 app.

Does anyone know how to refer to an image in the App/Resources/public/images folder, in a css-file that lives in the folder App/Resources/public/css ?

I am using Assetic, however these images transcend the level of bundles; they are "global" so to say (eg the company logo).

I've tried quit some combinations of urls, but the images are not found by Symfony2 and they are not dumped into the web folder.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter what frameworks you are using, it seems like you just want to go "up" one folder... just do `src="../images/imagename.png"`

Comment: It does matter in this case, as Symfony2 "renders" the css and copies the file to another location. In addition, the urls used in the css-file seem to get rewritten. At the moment it is a process of trial-and-error :)

Comment: Have you tried referencing off the root directory(eg: `"/images/logo.png"`) instead of relative paths?

Comment: Yes, and that is possible. My only concern is that in that case I am refering to the images in the web-folder directly (due to the rewrite that Symfony2 performs). Hence the images are not "picked up" from the app/Resources/public/images folder. In other words: Assetic is nowhere involved and when I switch from dev to prod mode, I will loose the images in the web folder (flush) and Symfony2 will not re-create them.

Comment: any light for this solution? i am in the same problem